# Easiest way to have an approximation of binary entropy inverse

Tags: inverse

I call $H_2$ the function $H_2(x) = -x \ln(x)-(1-x) \ln(1-x)$

It is the binary entropy.

I call $g(x)=H_2((1+x)/2)$

This last function is bijective on $[0;1]$.

I would like to have an inverse, or at least an approximation of its inverse (because from what I understood, it is a transcendental equation to find its inverse).

I tried to use the function `InverseFunction[g]` but it didn't work (it doesn't compute, it returns $g^{-1}(0.5)$ and not its value if I apply it on $y=0.5$ for example).

How could I do it in the **simplest way** in mathematica ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I like to use [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve) to find inverses when symbolic methods won't work. The ODE corresponding to the inverse of a function `g` can be obtained by differentiating the defining equation:

```
eqn = g[ginv[h]] == h;
D[eqn, h]
```

> g'[ginv[h]] ginv'[h] == 1

So, to find the inverse using [`NDSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolve), we need the above equation and an initial point. For example:

```
ginv = NDSolveValue[
    {ig'[h] == 1/g'[ig[h]], ig[g[1/2]] == 1/2},
    ig,
    {h, 0, 1},
    WorkingPrecision->20
];
```

> NDSolveValue::ndsz: At h == 0.69314717892280622909630802455704585678`20., step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.

```
Plot[{g[x], ginv[x]}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

[image]

I up the [`WorkingPrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision) so that complex numbers don't pollute the result when the inverse approaches zero.

Answer (score 4):

How about this? This samples the function `g` 100000 times an approximates the inverse of `g` by `Interpolation`:

```
H2 = x \[Function] -x Log[x] - (1 - x) Log[1 - x];
g = x \[Function] H2[(1 + x)/2];
xlist = Subdivide[0., 1., 100000];
ylist = Join[g[Most[xlist]], {0.}];
ginv = Interpolation[Transpose[{ylist, xlist}]];
```

Here is a plot of the approximate inverse function:

```
Show[
 Plot[g[x], {x, xlist[[1]], xlist[[-1]]}],
 Plot[ginv[y], {y, ylist[[1]], ylist[[-1]]}, PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]],
 PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1
 ]
```

[image]

And this helps to estimate the error (it seems to be of order `10^-8`):

```
Plot[{ginv[g[x]] - x, g[ginv[x]] - x}, {x, xlist[[1]], xlist[[-1]]}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Edit**

With `g` defined as a pure function as above, you can also use `ginv = InverseFunction[g]`:

```
Plot[InverseFunction[g][y], {y, ylist[[1]], ylist[[-1]]}]
```

[image]

But plotting takes *way* longer, probably because `InverseFunction` involves a root finding algorithm for each function evaluation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Indeed we can do trick but I wondered if there were like a "magic" function already implemented. But apparently not. I will use your trick (I'm a mathematica beginner so your example will be helpful)

Comment: As I added in the post, `InverseFunction` _does_ work for pure functions.

Comment: Actually I don't understand how InverseFunction knew on which part he took the inverse function. Indeed the function is not bijective and mathematica chose one of the branches. But where has this choice been put in the code ?

Comment: Honestly, I cannot tell what happens in the internals of `InverseFunction`... I guess it uses a root finding algorithm by bracketing the solution, but that's merely a shot into the dark.

Comment: Ok, so if I want to chose a specific branch i am forced to do your other method ?

Comment: "Forced" is a strong word. The interpolation method may be more robust and also more efficient, so there is some reason to prefer it. See also Carl Woll's answer; there you should also be able to pick a branch for your choice.

Comment: Sometimes I don't understand mathematica. Like why they didn't add an option allowing to select a branch because it is a very common problem...

Answer (score 3):

This is the same approach as Henrik's answer (didn't notice the answer while I was working on it). Since my method to generate the dataset used for interpolation seems slightly more straightforward, I'll leave this here anyway:

Define your functions:

```
Clear[h2, g]
h2[x_] := -x Log[x] - (1 - x) Log[1 - x]
g[x_] := h2[(1 + x)/2]
```

Generate an interpolation of the inverse by sampling `g` function:

```
ginv = Interpolation[
   With[{pitch = 1/1000}, Table[{g[x], x}, {x, 0, 1 - pitch, pitch}]]
 ];
```

Plotting the results:

```
Show[
 Plot[Legended[g[x], "g"], {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All],
 Plot[
   Legended[ginv[x], "inverse"], Flatten@{x, ginv["Domain"]},
   PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][2]
 ],
 Graphics[{Dashed, InfiniteLine[{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}]}],
 AspectRatio -> 1
]
```

[image: plot of g and its inverse]